# Programming Arduino Nano through Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, icsp

I am trying to Program arduino Nano using ICSP but the **problem is uploaded program only works as longs as Nano is connected to UNO**. Here is what i am trying.

1. Upload **arduinoISP** program in UNO.
2. Make connection b/w UNO and Nano.
3. Upload the my program to UNO(with Programmer Option as
   "Arduino as ISP" an board as Nano)

Something like [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Programming-Arduino-Nano-Using-UNO/)

Comment: `program only works as longs as Nano is connected to UNO` .... it makes no sense that this is a problem ... how do you expect to program the Nano if you do not connect it to the Uno?

Comment: What program did you load in? Does it include the Arduino bootloader?

Comment: @jsotola I am using UNO to just  upload the program into Nano, let's say a simple LED blinking. Obviously i am connecting UNO to Nano during upload, changed questions a little bit. pls check now.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany in #1 i uploaded sketch which makes UNO act as programmer, and in #3 i am uploading a simple led blinking program. More details about #1 are available on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the LED blinking program.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I belive led blinking program is the basic program:) and it  works as long as both  are connected.

Comment: Assuming it's getting 5V power and the reset line on the ICSP connector is disconnected, that pretty much leaves the program.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany reset line is not disconnected in my case.? Does it has to be ? Sorry! don't have much idea recently picked arduino.

Comment: If something is pulling it low, then the MCU will remain in the reset state (it is active LOW).